# Updating the Bullet Class. Why is the y-coordinate value decreasing when the bullet is going up?

Tags: python

I created a class to update the bullet's position in this alien invasion game from a book i'm reading called, "Python Crash Course". What i'm having trouble understanding is why is the bullet corresponding to a decreasing y-coordinate when it's going up? Also, why is it necessary to subtract the self.speed_factor which is (1) from self.y which would be the bullet.

Description of the Code here https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3c2x.jpg

```
def update(self):
     """Move the bullet up the screen."""
     # Update the decimal position of the bullet.
      self.y -= self.speed_factor
     # Update the rect position.
      self.rect.y = self.y

def draw_bullet(self):
     """Draw the bullet to the screen."""
     pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

Answer (score 0):

In (almost) all graphics engines, the X axis goes left to right. However, the *Y* axis goes top to bottom, the opposite of how we usually think of the Y axis. As you increase an object's Y coordinate, it will be moving downwards on the screen.

Comment: oh really? what is the purpose behind doing this? wouldn't it be more practical the other way around?

Comment: I'm not sure for certain, however I imagine that it's simply because computer screens are/used-to-be updated top to bottom.